# SLAM 3D reconstruction with kinect

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ccny-rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a 3d reconstruction using Point Cloud Data from My Kinect. Since I'm fairly new to the whole concept of SLAM, I'd appreciated if you can direct me into some links and give me suggestions to how can I manage that.

Some specifications: Ubuntu 12.04 and Kinect for Windows
Thanks in advance.

Hailu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88461/slam-3d-reconstruction-with-kinect/) by [hailukebede88](https://answers.ros.org/users/7531/hailukebede88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-10-09**:
I think you'll have a hard time getting the Kinect for Windows work with ROS/PCL, although it might be possible: http://pointclouds.org/news/2013/05/13/kinect-for-windows-with-pcl/ . The easiest solution is probably to just buy a regular Kinect for XBox or Asus Xtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While 3D SLAM cannot yet be considered a solved problem, here are two ROS packages that are quite popular for that task using the Kinect: [rgbdslam](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam) and [ccny_rgbd](http://wiki.ros.org/ccny_rgbd)

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hailukebede88](https://answers.ros.org/users/7531/hailukebede88/) on 2013-10-08**:
I'm using rgbdslam and installed the package following the steps provided in the "RGB-D SLAM for not ROS users" (the normal installation didn't work for me). Anyhow, what is the procedure I have to follow to compute a 3D reconstruction from my kinect once I installed the package? (silly question, maybe ... but ... I don't know a thing about this SLAM thing. And I don't have much time) ... Much thanks